# how to extract details from listview with checkbox?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

I want to keep the ability to select multiple contact numbers at a time using `checkbox`. I have used a custom layout with two `textview` and a `checkbox` to create a row for the list. I have successfully filled the list with the contacts but i am not able to configure how do i retrieve the phone numbers of the checked(ticked) contacts when the user clicks done button. Pls guide me.

[image: screenshot]

**custcontactview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5.0px"
android:paddingLeft="5.0px"
android:paddingTop="5.0px" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContactNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtContactName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_contacts_picker.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Selected" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShow" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ContacsPicker.java**

```
public class ContactsPicker extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

protected Object mActionMode;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_picker);
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "Name", "Phone" };
    int[] to = { R.id.txtContactName, R.id.txtContactNumber };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.custcontactview, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.clear();
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people
                .getString(people
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId,
                    null,
                    "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                            + ") ASC");
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                list.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();
    return list;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { }
}
```

Comment: you will need to override getView() method so that you can store the information(say in a ArrayList)  when a item is checked

Comment: @ShashankKadne can u pls complete my code. i have to submit my project on monday. and still very much is left to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a tag for each checkbox as well as an onCheckChanged listener or something similar. When the state changes to checked, just get the tag associated with that checkbox(so you will know which elements in your list was checked). Then you'll have to requery to get the phone number at that column index. You already have your phone number stored here

```
String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                                  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```